# traversing an html file to get a a href

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

My html file is as below

```
<div id="sidebar" style="top: 100px;">
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item hentry selected" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" data-id="3714235398193725034">

            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-FLnjwm6youQ/UUGhQei8KqI/AAAAAAAAAUE/nEl-5V5IcDw/s30-p/1.jpg" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">

            <h3 class="title entry-title" itemprop="name">


    <a href="http://mywebsiteurl/2013/03/blog-post.html" rel="bookmark" itemprop="url">art1</a>

  </h3>

        </div>
        <div class="item hentry" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" data-id="179325489509322215">
.
.
.
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The html has a div with id sidebar

Under that there is another div with class items

Under that there are multiple divs with class item

Under each div with class item I have a h3 with class title

Under h3 tag I have 'a' tag

I need to get the href values of 'a' tags under all divs with class item.

I would appreciate some help as to how to do the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first get all divs with class item using `getElementsByClassName`and then for each div find all the anchor tags under that div using `getElementsByTagName`.

```js
const itemDivs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('item')];

const hrefs = [];
itemDivs.forEach(div => {
    const anchors = [...div.getElementsByTagName('a')];
    if (anchors && anchors.length > 0) {
        anchors.forEach(a => hrefs.push(a.href));
    }
});

console.log(hrefs); // prints ["http://mywebsiteurl/2013/03/blog-post.html"]
```

Comment: I have a h3 tag between my div tag and a tag

Comment: The `Element.getElementsByTagName()` method returns a live `HTMLCollection` of elements with the given tag name. All descendants of the specified element are searched, but not the element itself. All a tags under the div is retrieved by `getElementsByTagName()`. It will get the `a` tag even if there is an `h3` tag between the `div` and `a` tags.

Comment: Also the h3 tag has classname title, so I tried with that and it worked but the problem is that the array hrefs has 1345 values but in the browser console it shows a few and then ...

Answer (score 1):

Once try with inline jQuery:

```js
$.each($("#sidebar .items .item h3 a"),function(a,b){console.log($(b).attr("href"));});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar" style="top: 100px;">
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item hentry selected" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" data-id="3714235398193725034">

            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-FLnjwm6youQ/UUGhQei8KqI/AAAAAAAAAUE/nEl-5V5IcDw/s30-p/1.jpg" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">

            <h3 class="title entry-title" itemprop="name">


    <a href="http://mywebsiteurl/2013/03/blog-post.html" rel="bookmark" itemprop="url">art1</a>

  </h3>

        </div>
        <div class="item hentry" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" data-id="179325489509322215">
           <img class="thumbnail" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-FLnjwm6youQ/UUGhQei8KqI/AAAAAAAAAUE/nEl-5V5IcDw/s30-p/1.jpg" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">

            <h3 class="title entry-title" itemprop="name">


    <a href="http://example.com" rel="bookmark" itemprop="url">art2</a>

  </h3>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) api

```js
let html = `<div id="sidebar" style="top: 100px;">
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item hentry selected" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" data-id="3714235398193725034">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-FLnjwm6youQ/UUGhQei8KqI/AAAAAAAAAUE/nEl-5V5IcDw/s30-p/1.jpg" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
            <h3 class="title entry-title" itemprop="name">
    <a href="http://mywebsiteurl/2013/03/blog-post.html" rel="bookmark" itemprop="url">art1</a>
  </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item hentry" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" data-id="179325489509322215">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class = 'item'>
   <a  href='http://example1.com'/> 
  </div>
  <div class = 'noitem'>
   <a  href='http://example2.com'/> 
  </div>
</div>`

let parser = new DOMParser()
let parsed = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')

let anchors = [...parsed.querySelectorAll('.item > a')]

let hrefs = anchors.map(v=> v.href)

console.log(hrefs)
```

Comment: If you see my code you will find there is a div with class items which has a div with class item which has a h3 tag which has a a href with value http://mywebsiteurl/2013/03/blog-post.html, This is the value i want.. I do not have the additional divs you added